# Problems with SQL2022 always on alert 1480 on failover

Tags: sql-server

We have a three node **sql2022** cluster that is using the always on functionality.
I have a need to start a job to perform some maintenance task when an instance fails over from one node to another. Unfortunately not everything is shared.

For this I found a lot of documentation on the web pointing out I can configure an alert on the SQL job agent for this and that I should use alert 1480. Like for example https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3489/configure-sql-server-alerts-and-notifications-for-alwayson-availability-groups/.

However when trying this I am left with several questions and problems.

- First, where do I configure the alert? In SQL 2022 the master database is virtualized per instance. So do I configure the alert on the Cluster instance or on the individual nodes. In earlier versions jobs were always on the node, but with the new virtual master db this changed.
- Second I tried configuring it on the node and on the cluster and I noticed I get far more then a single 1480 message. I don't know for sure, but I think I am getting one alert per database on the instance. That is not what I want. I need 1 alert when the node fails over.
- Third, When the alert kicks of it kicks of on the old primary *and* the new primary. I added a step to the job to detect if the server is primary, but for some time after failover alert, both nodes involved return that they are primary and there are a few intermediate states too. The alert happen *before* the failover is completed. I want an alert when it's done.

This is confusing me a lot.

I simply want a single alert per instance on failover when is completed and ready. So I can start a single job, preferably only on the new primary.

How do I get that?
(If not possible, best possible is welcome to)